# Java Android Compare Times from String Format

Tags: java, android, date, time, compare

I have a String that contains a Time in the following format:

```
"hh:mm tt"
```

For Example you could represent the current time as "7:04 PM"

How can I compare this to the current time in the user's time zone to see if this time is less than, equal to, or greater than the current time?

Comment: I need this to be as efficient as possible since it will be executed in a Service.

Comment: if you just have 7:04 PM and not the offset, how do you hope to compare it to an offset time in the users local timezone?  Or are your times based off of a specific offset?

Comment: They are based on a specific offset.

Comment: Personally then I would put the time into a 24hr format and just do the math directly on the hour/minutes/seconds...etc (whatever granularity you need) and then apply the offset to the result.

Comment: So you are recommending this as opposed to create Calendar() or Date() objects?

Comment: The Calendar() object does have methods for determining date/time differences so it may be beneficial to use that.  I don't know how optimized it may be, and if it will require you to create any intermediary objects to box up your "7:04 PM" into the correct timezone.  For this I would try two approaches, one with doing the math yourself, and another creating the required intermediary objects to box up the times into calendar objects so you can use the  after/before methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert `String` to `Date`.

```
String pattern = "<yourPattern>";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
try {
 Date one = dateFormat.parse(<yourDate>);
 Date two = dateFormat.parse(<yourDate>);

}
catch (ParseException e) {}
```

It's implements Comparable interface so you should be able to compare them with `compareTo()`

---

**Edit:** 
I forgot but you know it but only for sure compareTo return -1, 1 or 0 so `one.compareTo(two)` returns -1 when first ist before second etc.

Answer (score 3):

The following code elaborates on @Sajmon's answer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String currentTimeStr = "7:04 PM";

    Date userDate = new Date();
    String userDateWithoutTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(userDate);

    String currentDateStr = userDateWithoutTime + " " + currentTimeStr;
    Date currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd h:mm a").parse(currentDateStr);

    if (userDate.compareTo(currentDate) >= 0) {
        System.out.println(userDate + " is greater than or equal to " + currentDate);
    } else {
        System.out.println(userDate + " is less than " + currentDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse says that you must surround SimpleDateFormat.parse() with a try catch block.

Comment: Yes, this is true. In the code above, the `main` method throws a `ParseException`. In your code, just like in @Sajmon's answer, I expect you'll be surrounding `parse` with a try-catch block.